# Jquery URL Parameter

Tags: jquery, url

I've got this function:

```
$.urlParam = function(name){
            var results = new RegExp('[\?&]' + name + '=([^&#]*)').exec(window.location.href);
            if (results==null){
                return null;
            }
            else{
                return results[1] || 0;
            }
        };
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/h0typaqx/)

I put a `?param1` behind the URL but nothing is showing up, the firebug console doesn't say anything.

Can you guys help me?

Comment: This won't work in a fiddle as it will read the URL of the `result` `iframe`, not the URL of the main page.

Comment: I know, but the Fiddle is an example of the rest of the code.

Comment: Are you "typing" `?param1` in the address bar?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get the value from the URL parameter?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/979975/how-to-get-the-value-from-the-url-parameter)

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/yc5f9ct7/2/

Comment: Your regex is looking for the `value` of the `param`. So put `?param=something` and your should get `something`